# Server-side validation rule is not being found

Tags: cms, jform, validations

I've added a custom field to com_content, and everything has been working wonderfully.  I'm now trying to add some server side validation, and after following all the tutorials and examples I've been able to find, specifically [this one](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=782606&view=next), it is failing because the rule isn't being found

The desired rule is almost identical to validating a Username, so I copyied/renamed that as my starting point. The files/paths DO exist, and load/save is working properly.

Is there additional information that I'm not providing or perhaps fresh eyes that will make me feel foolish when it's pointed out?

From the B/E, clicking on "Save" produces this error:

**An error has occurred.**

0 JForm::validateField() rule `mycode` missing.

**Custom Field XML** (Works as expected, except server validation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/rules">
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="MyFields" label="My Info">
            <field name="my_code"
                type="text" size="15"
                validate="mycode"
                label="My Code"
                />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

**/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/rules/mycode.php**

```
//jimport('joomla.form.formrule');   does not work with or without this
class JFormRuleMycode extends JFormRule
{
    public function test(SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null, JRegistry $input = null, JForm $form = null) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you actually have to specify what the path is for and put it in the right place, lol!  The problem was in specifying a path for the *fields* instead of for the *rules*!

This correction fixed the problem:

```
<form>
    <fields name="params" addrulepath="/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/rules">
```