# How can I provide a custom message for a failed JFormRule validation?

Tags: jform, custom-action

When validating a custom field, and the test fails, Joomla returns the following default error message:

```
**Warning** Invalid field: My Field
```

How can I specify the message that is returned to explain why it is invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `message` attribute, but better like this:

```
<field name="my_code" type="text" size="15" label="My Code"
  validate="myrule" message="Field may only contain A-z or 0-9" />
```

:)

Comment: didn't work. i've place the attribute with custom message but all i see is Invalid field: Title when submit.

Comment: Agree with prev comment. Doesn't work on Joomla 3.6.5. Is the behaviour dependent on the template used?

Answer (score 1):

For an message that may vary, add the `message` attribute like this:

```
public function test(SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null, JRegistry $input = null, JForm $form = null)
{
    if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/i', $value)) {
        $element->addAttribute('message', 'Field may only contain A-z or 0-9');
        return false;
    }elseif(!$somethingelse) {
        $element->addAttribute('message', 'Something else is wrong');
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: which file to add this code?

Comment: Take a look at this question/answer for some of the details of form validation:  http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/server-side-validation-rule-is-not-being-found

Comment: A lighter weight condition that acts the same as your regular expression is the often overlooked `ctype_alnum()` function.  `if (!ctype_alnum($value)) {`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php