# How to use a regex to validate a FormField?

Tags: form-fields-types, regex, validation

Is there a way to simply validate a form field with a regular expression?

I thought about something like this:

```
<field name="firstname" type="text" label="Firstname"
       validate="regex" regex=".*" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no native answer I have a solution to do this with an own JFormRule class.

Create a file in your component/models/form/rules directory called regex.php
Insert the source below

```
class componentnameFormRuleRegex extends JFormRule {

    public function test(&$element, $value, $group = null, &$input = null, &$form = null)   {

        $this->regex = (string)$element['regex'];

        return parent::test($element, $value, $group, $input, $form);
    }   
}
```

Add the path to your rules directory to the `addRulePath` attribute in the xml file and add `validate="componentname.regex"` and `regex="$regularexpression$"` to the field you want to validate.

The class adds the value of the `regex` attribute to the `JFormRule` and uses the native test function for validation.

Comment: This looks like a winning solution.  Might you award yourself the green tick to mark this page as resolved?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Client Side Validation](https://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation) for this, however You will need to make a [Custom Form Field](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type) for this to happen.

Assuming you're using Joomla 3.4, you first need to initialise the validation script, like so:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidator');
```

Then for your field, you need to add the class `validate-changeme`

```
<field name="firstname" type="text" label="Firstname" class="validate-changeme" />
```

Then in your custom form field script, you can add your regex for the validation like so:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration("
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       document.formvalidator.setHandler('changeme', function(value) {
          regex=/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
          return regex.test(value);
       });
    });
");
```

Remember to replace `changeme` with what ever suits your needs.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx for your answer, but frontend validation is only a cosmetic thing. I found out that the JFormRule class is a simple regex validation class but doesn't find a way to use it directly.

Comment: @HaraldLeithner - Ahh yes, you're right. Have a look at [this question/answer](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12257/how-to-use-a-regex-to-valid-a-formfield/12258?noredirect=1#comment16549_12258)

Comment: your link is wrong, could you fix it?

Comment: @HaraldLeithner - Oops, sorry: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/server-side-validation-rule-is-not-being-found